# extract alpha numeric id

Tags: regex

I am looking to use RE to extract an id and description from the input which is in following format:

```
TTTT.1.A8This is important
AA.1.2.2ANothing is sometimes important
AAC.1A.2Everything sometimes is not important
```

Expected result:

```
ID         description
TTTT.1.A8  This is important
AA.1.2.2A  Nothing is sometimes important
AAC.1A.2   Everything sometimes is not important
```

```
I tried to achieve it as below:
img1 =  re.compile(r"\w+\.\d+")

for in in input:

   if re.search(img1,i.text):    
     req_id = str.strip(re.search(img1,i.text).group(0))
    
     req_text = str.strip(re.split(img1,i.text)[1])
     control_ids[req_id] = req_text
```

Comment: Does the `Desctiption` always start with an uppercase letter? How many uppercase letters can there be at the end of the `ID`?

Comment: I'd start with something like `^([\d\w.]+\d+[A-Z]{0,1})([A-Z].*)$`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew the ID normally ends with a Capital letter or just a number.

Comment: Is there a max of 2 characters after the last dot of ID?

Comment: @zer00ne The id can be separated with upto 4 DOT qualifiers . Yes ,the end is always a number or  character or combination of number and character.

Comment: Try `^([A-Z0-9]+(?:\.[A-Z0-9]+)*)([A-Z].*)$` (see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/lrq6kk/1)). Are you using Pandas?

Comment: @sagargahalod OK, I think I [got it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72807504/2813224)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find an upper case letter followed by a lower case letter:

```
/([A-Z][a-z])/g
```

then replace it as a space and itself  `$1` for JavaScript  `\g<1>` for Python.

JavaScript: [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/PKRQPb/1)

Python: [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/VZD5mr/1)

```js
const str =`TTTT.1.A8This is important
AA.1.2.2ANothing is sometimes important
AAC.1A.2Everything sometimes is not important`;

const rgx = new RegExp(/([A-Z][a-z])/, 'g');

const output = str.replace(rgx, ` $1`);

console.log(output);
```